# How to format a momentjs Duration to be human-readable?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, iso8601

I have an array of ISO 8601 durations that I want to sum, and then display in a human readable format.
The times look like `PT10M33S`, `PT3H00M00S`, `PT50H23M15S`. I used [moment js](http://www.momentjs.com) to parse them with `moment.duration()` but when I add them together I don't know how to turn them into something readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a few hours, I discovered the [`moment-duration-format`](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) plugin. You would call `.format()` on a duration object and pass a string that formats it to what you want to display. Here is what I ended up writing:

```
function formatDuration(duration, format_string) {
  var length;
  if (format_string === "long") {
    format = [
      duration.months() === 1 ? "Month" : "Months",
      duration.days() === 1 ? "Day" : "Days",
      duration.hours() === 1 ? "Hour" : "Hours",
      duration.minutes() === 1 ? "Minute" : "Minutes",
      duration.seconds() === 1 ? "Second" : "Seconds"
    ];
    length = duration.format("M [" + format[0] + "] d [" + format[1] +
    "] h [" + format[2] + "] m [" + format[3] + " and] s [" + format[4] + "]");
  } else if (format_string === "short") {
    length = duration.format("M[m] d[d] h:mm:ss");
  } else {
    length = duration.format(format_string);
  };
  return length;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

according to the moment docs https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/ you could do:

```
duration.humanize();
// or if the duration is given in other values like seconds:
moment.duration(60, "seconds").humanize(); // a minute
```

to display duration in a custom format:

```
moment.utc(duration.as('milliseconds')).format('HH:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
> var d = moment.duration(125, 's')
undefined
> moment().subtract(d).fromNow().replace(/ ago/, '')
'2 minutes'
```